# recursion in generator

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, generator

Is there some special behaviors when using recursion in generator?

I can print 0,1,2,3,4 by following code:

```
def generator_recursion(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    else:
        generator_recursion(n-1)
        print(n)
    
generator_recursion(4)
```

But when I change to generator like below code, It only print 4.  I don't know why. please help.

```
def generator_recursion(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    else:
        generator_recursion(n-1)
        yield n
    
gr = generator_recursion(4)
for k in gr:
   print(k)
```

Comment: Because you only ever yield `n`. What about the recursive call?

Comment: the function execution flow should be simple and clear. is there are some difference between function and generator function in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [`yield from`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#yield-expressions) the recursion.

```
def generator_recursion(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    else:
        yield from generator_recursion(n-1)
        yield n
    
gr = generator_recursion(4)
for k in gr:
    print(k)
```

This prints:

```
0
1
2
3
4

​
```

Comment: thank you! It looks work! But I still don't understand why. I can't find more information for yield from. Do you know where i can get more information?

Comment: in the case, do i have to use yield from?

Comment: Yeah, `yield from` is the normal way (you could wrap the inner on in a for loop, but that's not great). There's info in [PEP 380](https://peps.python.org/pep-0380/) but it gets into the weeds. The main issue is the function `generator_recursion()` returns a generator object that yields values. When you call it recursively with `generator_recursion(n-1)` you want to outer generator to yield the results from the inner one. That's what `yield from` does.

Comment: PEP380 is exact the thing i need. thanks! Generator is quite different from normal function.

Comment: @FerntreeGuy In this particular case, `yield from generator_recursion(n-1)` is mostly equivalent to `for x in generator_recursion(n-1): yield x`. This is not really different from other recursive functions. If your recursive call returned a value, you'd still need to do something with that value.

Answer (score 1):

You must `yield` from the recursive sub-process -

```py
def generator_recursion(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    else:
        for k in generator_recursion(n-1): # ✅ for k in sub-process
            yield k  # ✅ yield sub-process values
        yield n
```

Because `generator_recursion` is properly `yield`ing from the recursive call, you will now see the proper output -

```py
gr = generator_recursion(4)
for k in gr:
   print(k)
```

As you have learned, this is precisely what `yield from …` accomplishes -

```py
def generator_recursion(n):
    if n < 0:
        return
    else:
        yield from generator_recursion(n-1) # ✅ equivalent to above
        yield n
```